# Cant sort null with comparator

Tags: java, spring, guava, comparator

I keep getting a `nullpointerexception` when I try to sort users where a certain user has a null value in his profile. I was under the impression `Google Collection` would handle these null values, but it doesnt seem to work.

**This is the code I use:**

```
Comparator<UserModel> firstName_comparator = new Comparator<UserModel>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(UserModel c1, UserModel c2) {
        return c1.getProfile().getFirstName().toLowerCase()
                .compareTo(c2.getProfile().getFirstName().toLowerCase());
        }
 };
 Collections.sort(users, Ordering.from(firstName_comparator).nullsLast());
```

---

This specific line throws the `nullpointerexception`:

```
.compareTo(c2.getProfile().getFirstName().toLowerCase());
```

Its because `getProfile()` is null.
 How can I fix this? I want to be able to sort my users with null values.

Comment: I dont understand how this is a duplicate to that question. I was asking (maybe not directly) how to fix it (if possible) with Google Collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Guava won't ignore your NullPointerException. You're providing a Comparator, and this comparator is supposed to respect the Comparator contract. Throwing NullPointerException is not part of the contract.

```
String firstName1 = c1.getProfile() == null? null : c1.getProfile().getFirstName().toLowerCase();
String firstName2 = c2.getProfile() == null? null : c1.getProfile().getFirstName().toLowerCase();

return Ordering.natural().nullsFirst().compare(firstName1, firstName2);
// or nullsLast(), depending on what you prefer
```

Or, simpler:

```
Comparator<UserModel> comparator = 
    Ordering.natural()
            .nullsFirst()
            .onResultOf(model -> c1.getProfile() == null? null : c1.getProfile().getFirstName().toLowerCase());
```

Comment: What if `getFirstName()` returns null?

Comment: It will throw an NPE. If firstName can be null, then the OP needs to add yet another null check.

Comment: Yup. That's precisely the question. Where is the `NullPointerException` coming from.

Comment: No, that's not the question. The OP knows that the NPE is caused by getProfile() returning null. And of course, calling getFirstName() on null causes an NPE.

Comment: I feel"Its because getProfile() is null?" was a question rather than a statement. But I guess the question is closed now.

Comment: Thx for the clarification, problem solved! @CKing, in the end it was the firstname that was null, so I changed Jb's code a bit. I had a similar situation where the profile was null, so I assumed it was the same in this case.

Comment: @RichardAvalos In that case, I believe you should be accepting my answer :)

Comment: @JBNizet I guess I was right about the question being about the source of the`NullPointerException` after all ;)

Comment: Just out of curiousity, how come your 2nd solution still returns a NPE? Comparator<UserModel> comparator
                            = Ordering.natural().nullsFirst()
                            .onResultOf((UserModel c1) -> c1.getProfile() == null ? null : c1.getProfile().getFirstName().toLowerCase());
                    Collections.sort(users, comparator);

Comment: @RichardAvalos Because getFirstName() returns null and you're still calling toLowerCase() on it? Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it? Because that seems to be the crux of your question: you don't seem to understand what an NPE is.

Comment: bleh, i feel so dumb for not doing a null check on firstname instead of profile. Thx for waking me up!

Answer (score 1):

> I was under the impression Google Collection would handle these null
>   values

The [nullLast](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#nullsLast()) method will only check if a particular element in the collection is `null` and place it at the end of the collection.

> This specific line throws the nullpointerexception:
>
> `.compareTo(c2.getProfile().getFirstName().toLowerCase());`

There are two possibilities for nulls here :

1. `c2.getProfile()` is null
2. `c2.getProfile().getFirstName()` is null

You need to explicitly safeguard your `Comparator` implementation from these `null`s.